# Create ListBox DataTemplate in C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to create a generic view, and I want it to contain a ListBox with a datatemplate

I want to create it either using pure C# code or if possible load it through xaml? If I can create a template I can get in c# as a resource of sorts.

What I have made until now is

```
        private static ListBox CreateDayListBox()
    {
        var listBox = new ListBox();
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        var grid = new Grid();
        var columnDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Auto};
        var columnDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition1);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition2);

        var rectangleItemBought = new Rectangle {Width = 50, Height = 50};
        rectangleItemBought.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, new Binding("Bought"));
        grid.Children.Add(rectangleItemBought);

        var textBlockItemName = new TextBlock();
        textBlockItemName.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        var textBlockItemQuantity = new TextBlock();
        textBlockItemQuantity.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Quantity"));
        var textBlockItemQuantityType = new TextBlock();
        textBlockItemQuantityType.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("QuantityType"));

        var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
        Grid.SetColumn(stackpanel, 1);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textBlockItemName);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textBlockItemQuantity);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textBlockItemQuantityType);
        grid.Children.Add(stackpanel);

        return listBox;
    }
```

So I want the listbox datatemplate to contain 1 rectangle, 1 stackpanel with 3 textboxes inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the template in XAML then load it in your code.

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx).

Besides, I'm pretty sure you can create the DataTemplate by code the same way you created the controls, look at this code ([credit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f230804d-fc0f-4321-a61e-69a2c890b28d#e3217315-66dc-43e1-91c3-909311c9490f)):

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory factory =
  new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
template.VisualTree = factory;
FrameworkElementFactory childFactory =
  new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
childFactory.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Machine.Thumbnail"));
childFactory.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, 170.0);    
childFactory.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, 170.0);
factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
childFactory.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty,
  new Binding("Machine.Descriiption"));
childFactory.SetValue(Label.WidthProperty, 170.0);
childFactory.SetValue(Label.HorizontalAlignmentProperty,
  HorizontalAlignment.Center);
factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
```

Comment: Should work, but can see this method dont work on WP7 (which I didnt mention, didnt knew it would matter)

Comment: Which method? The code above is pseudu... I'm sure WP7 (never used it tho) offers XAML parsing.